# Laragon use https on local network

Tags: https, openssl, laragon

I'm lost with all informations about ssl, https....

Here the story : I build a laravel website at my work hosted on our windows server with laragon. Every computer go to this site with ip of the serveur, i.e. http://192.17.10.168/aurora/public/login

It works only with local computer and we want to keep that privacy (no need outside access).

But now I want to use tools that use https : http/2, progressive app...

How can I use https with that config ?

I succefully add openssl certificat to my aurora.test on serveur but http2 doesn't work, my config :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
Protocols h2 http/1.1
DocumentRoot "${DOCROOT}/aurora2/public"
ServerName aurora.test:443

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/laragon/ssl/app.dev.key
SSLCertificateFile C:/laragon/ssl/app.dev.crt
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

I enable module on apache config.

How others local computers can access to my https site with aurora .test ?

Thank for your help !